# Magento cms page xml layout product view block pass product_id variable

Tags: magento

I created CMS Page in Magento and I would like to set product ID. In xml layout update is:

```
<reference name="content">
   <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
   <action method="setData">
      <name>product_id</name>
      <value>1</value>
   </action>
   <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
   <block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
      <label>Alert Urls</label>
   </block>
   <action method="setTierPriceTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml</template></action>
   <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
      <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
      <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action>
   </block>
   <block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />
   <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
      <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
   </block>
   <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
   <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
   </block>
   <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
   <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
   <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" translate="label">
      <label>Product View Extra Hint</label>
   </block>
   <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
      <label>Info Column Options Wrapper</label>
   <block type="core/template" name="options_js" template="catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml"/>
   <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
      <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
      <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
      <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
      <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
   </block>
   <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
   </block>
   <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml" translate="label">
       <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
       <action method="insert"><block>product.tierprices</block></action>
       <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml"/>
       <action method="append"><block>product.info.addtocart</block></action>
       <action method="append"><block>product.info.addto</block></action>
   </block>
   <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
       <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
       <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
       <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
       <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
   </block>
   <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
       <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
       <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
       <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
       <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
   </block>
       <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container1</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
       <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container2</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
   </block>
```

I try set product ID by setData function but I have message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getMetaTitle() on a non-object in ...\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\View.php on line 56

I try also insert code in content:

> {{block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml" product_id="1"}}

Above code display product page but childHtml methods doesn't render child blocks. How can I pass product_id variable to block that it display product page with child blocks ?

Comment: You are trying to set product ID??? I can't understand from the above that what you are going to do?? Can you explain the your requirement as detailed??

Comment: I would like to view product with a specific ID on cms page using product view block and its child block.

Comment: I would like generate a product info xml file with his ID and all other informations. And in result all I get is error I mentioned above